# Titan 1.0.0 graph cache memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, java-8, titan, apache-tomee

I am running **TomEE** (kind of Tomcat) server on **Java 8** and using **Titan 1.0.0** with Cassandra backend and Elasticsearch index as my database. In my development environment with small user connection everything works perfect but on my production server with many user connected with many db access we have an issue with memory leaks probably because Titan graph cache or something Titan relative. I have configure 4GB heap-size and after more than 10 hours of run allocated memory on heap grows to its maximum (~300Mb per hour) and it causes that GC (Garbage Collector) can't clean up anymore and remains to run continuously that causes server instance to be unresponsive.
Using VisualVM i did some memory profiling and those are my screenshots:
[image: Allocated memory graph]
[image: Heap histogram]
Any suggest how we can fix this or find the way to investigate this issue in more details? May be some GC params can help us in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen those problems before on Titan 1.0 with Cassandra. Two things to check:

**Opening And Closing The Graph**

Are you opening different transaction to the graph per user or different graphs per user? i.e. are you doing:

(1)

```
//User 1 Logs in
graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
//User 2 Logs in
graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
```

or

(2)

```
graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
//User 1 Logs in
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
//User 2 Logs in
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
```

Approach (1) means that each user gets their own connection to the graph with their own graph object. This is very heavy and leads to more memory usage.

Approach (2) means that every user uses the same connection but different transactions. This is preferable in my opinion. **Note: This is assuming users are on different threads.**

**Long lived Transactions**

This is the problem I had which resulted in similar GC problems to yourself. I simply kept transactions alive for too long. To speed up querying Titan caches a lot and I don't think it clears the cache unless the transaction is closed. So ideally you should have something like:

```
graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
//User 1 Logs in
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
graph.tx().close();
//User 2 Logs in
soStuffWithGraph(graph);
graph.tx().close();
```

where each transaction is closed after a user is done with it.

Comment: I am using the second approach. I have one opened connection to the graph and open new transaction `TitanTransaction tt = graph.newTransaction()` for each user request. Each transaction is short (add or update one or two vertices or edges  OR query data from vertices) and at the end transaction is always committed `tt.commit()` or roll-backed `tt.rollback()` in case of failure (before throwing some exception)

Comment: Is you using `graph.newTransaction()` then you are creating [multi-threaded transactions](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/tx.html#multi-thread-tx) which creates a whole new transaction handling object which is also quite heavy and always open. If you *explicitly* creating one for each user then you should definitely be calling `tt.close()` at the end. Otherwise it will remain open.

Comment: From Titan [documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index.html) and [javadoc](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/1.0.0/) I thought that `tt.commit()` and `tt.rollback()` will close transaction BUT after adding `tt.close()` next to each commit and rollback it solves our memory leaks.